# Run VBScript using C#

Tags: c#, vbscript, reference

I am trying to execute a script written in `VBScript`, in a `C#` class library project

```
using System.Web.UI;  //reference added at top

MSScriptControl script = new ScriptControl();
script.Language = "VBScript";
script.AddObject("Repository", connectToDB.GetRepository);
```

I get the following compilation error:

> Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MSScriptControl' could not
>   be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Any ideas?

Comment: are they under the same namespace? or did you add reference correctly?

Comment: @IJ, I added it correctly - just wanted to clarify that the reference was added. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add a COM reference of "Microsoft Script Control 1.0" to your project.
2. `using Microsoft.VisualBasic;`
3. Use this code: ​​

   ```
   MSScriptControl.ScriptControl script = new MSScriptControl.ScriptControl();
   script.Language = "VBScript";
   script.AddObject("Repository", connectToDB.GetRepository);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I belive

```
MSScriptControl script = new ScriptControl();
```

should be

```
MSScriptControl.ScriptControl sc = new MSScriptControl.ScriptControl();
```